# Excel: How to delete all text to the right of specific string

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a bunch of web sites in a list, with junk characters after the .com/.org, etc. I need to remove all characters after the .com/.org, but keep the .com/.org. For example:

**these** 
sitename.com - platypus 
websiteplace.com - gargoyle

**become** 
sitename.com
websiteplace.com

I've searched around a bunch and can't find something that works quite that way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this formula: `=LEFT(A1;FIND(".";A1&".")+3)` , A1 beeing your "sitename.com - platypus " cell.

Comment: Remove everything after (and including) the first space encountered in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your data are in column A, then in the adjacent cell, write this formula:

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2)
```

Check the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I ended up using a variant of this. Like this:

=LEFT(D2,FIND(".com",D2)+3)

Do you know if it's possible to 'nest' finds in that, so for example have that one formula do the same thing but also find .org, .net, .info, etc?

Comment: @Klarg you can use array constants.  Don't forget you'll also need to check the length of the found domain.